# How to enable/disable reactive feature of Spring webflux application

Tags: spring-webflux

I just want to take metric of spring webflux application with reactive and without reactive.

```
 @RestController
 class BusinessController {
  public **Mono<BiznessObj>** getDetails() {
 \\logics
  }
 }
```

Is it possible to turn on/off reactive feature in spring webflux app without rewrite app with spring webmvc.
some thing like,

```
spring.reactive.enabled= true --Will response reactive Mono<BiznessObj>
spring.reactive.enabled= false --Will response Mono<BiznessObj> but not in reactive way
```

Switch spring webflux reactive application to behave normal IO blocking application like spring webmvc